# C# Length method

Tags: c#, .net, validation

I'm looking how to use correctly the Lenght method, I'm not c# developer, first time looking into code so basically try to get throw using documentation, so I build an validation code that uses string.IsNullOrEmpty to check if the fieldName.name is either empty or null, this is working

```
var namepropName = PathFinder<InfoField>.Get(i => i.fieldName.name);

  RegValidation(namepropName, (x, y) => {

     ValueRequired(, () => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.fieldName.name));

});
```

Now I trying to check if the fieldName.name length is bigger than 20 characters.

The below code is throwing errors, how can I use string.Length is bigger than 20 correctly?

`ValueRequired(, () => string.Length > 20 (x.fieldName.name));`

Comment: First thing to learn when eve ntrying to program:" The above code is throw errors" - MAKE A PROPER ERROR REPORT. Tell us which error. Likely either x or x.fieldname are null.

Comment: I think you need some basic tutorial in c# syntax. You are trying to run before even learning how to crawl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ValueRequired(, () => x.fieldName.name.Length > 20);
```

Comment: I think you need a variable before the initial ',' (comma) in your parameter list.  Even something like:  `ValueRequired(string.Empty, () => x.fieldName.name.Length > 20);` But even then I think the syntax needs more refinement.

Comment: thanks that worked!